# Use query that reflexts structure to determine records with Joins

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables:
roles, facilities and organisations

facilities contain 2 items:

```
'NAME'
'ORG'
```

Organisations contain 4 items:

```
'ORG'
'CLUSTER'
'HUB'
```

Roles contain 6 items, ROLE determines the org part

```
'ROLE'
'FACILITY'
'ORG'
'CLUSTER'
'HUB'
'USER'
```

A structure would look like this:

```
HUB => CLUSTER => ORG => FACILITY
```

When I would like to request all ROLES that I have rights for, I need to:

1. Get all my roles
2. For each role, see what underlying ORGS would be appliccable for me, e.g.

   'ROLE' = 'CLUSTER'
   'CLUSTER' = '1'
   I need to get all 'ORG' where 'CLUSTER' = '1'
   I need then to get all ROLES where these 'ORG' are.
   I need then to get all ROLES where FACILITIES are from FACILITIES that have these 'ORG'

   For HUB this counts for CLUSTER and ORG.

In text: 'A role for an organisation part can see all roles below him, down to facility level'

I cannot really change the structure here, and my SQL knowledge is really not enough to get started. But I think the information should be sufficient to do these kind or requests?

Comment: Could paste an example of input data and expected output?

Comment: I'm lost at the first sentence:  "I have two tables".  Then you list three tables.  Sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation would all help.  In addition, tables have columns and rows.  They do not have "items", so your description is unclear.